# what is the correct regular expression to search for phrases with spaces?

Tags: regex, dreamweaver

I have a site added in dreamweaver and I would like to search for all instances where a named anchor exists with a space. For example:

```
<a name="Some named anchor">
<a href="#Some named anchor">
```

So I can replace it with:

```
<a name="Somenamedanchor">
<a href="#Somenamedanchor">
```

Comment: Use your HTML parser to get the attributes, then simply apply `s/\s//g`.

Answer (score -1):

To find each name attribute containing spaces

```
name="([^"]*)\s+([^"]*)"
```

To find each href attribute containing spaces

```
href="([^"]*)\s+([^"]*)"
```

Comment: hi brad, thanks but how do i replace it with the value without spaces? I am doing a find and replace.

Comment: tried it but it catches the spaces outside of the anchor tag. like <a name="anchor"> <span class=...

Comment: Those regexen are too greedy. But then, don't parse HTML with regex in the first place.

Comment: Sorry dats, I forgot to exclude the quotation mark. I've updated the regexp to make it less 'greedy'. This will not allow you to do an automatic find and replace, just a find.